# Will the static variable be released when set its value =null?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Following are my code : 
Will the Dispose method that static log=null cause memory leak? If yes, how to avoid this and release static log resources?..

```
public class LogUtil:IDisposable
{
   private StreamWriter logwriter;
   private LogUtil(StreamWriter sw)
   {
       this.logwriter = sw;
   }


public void Dispose()
       {
           if (log != null)
           {
               this.logwriter.Close();
               this.logwriter.Dispose();               
               log = null;
           }
       }

   private static LogUtil log = null;
 public static LogUtil getTodayLog()
 {
     if (log == null)
     {
         String logfilePath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + String.Format("\\{0}{1}{2}.log", DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);
         StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logfilePath, true, Encoding.UTF8);
         log = new LogUtil(sw);
         return log;
     }
     else
         return log;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it will not cause memory leaks, as long as the `Dispose` is called.

I do wonder though why it is a static in the first place. Can't `log` be a non-static class member or not be set to `null`? Disposing a `static` at instance destruction doesn't really make sense.

In my opinion, this `static` logging helper *could* stay alive until application end.